# java programming: how to move the display

Tags: java

im making a side scroller and i dont know how to side scroll and im trying to scroll on the x and y axis
this is for a school project so i would like help as soon as possable

heres some of my code if you have question just ask. any advice is welcome.

source code http://www.mediafire.com/?fi1f9lv6qc2t5d7

gameCanvas.java

```
package Game;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class GameCanvas extends Canvas implements Runnable,KeyListener{
 public static final long ONE_SECOND_MILI = 1000;
 protected int frameW;
 protected int frameH;
 protected long fps;
 private long period = 15;
 private BufferStrategy buff;
 private Graphics graph;
 private Color bckGround=(Color.GRAY);
 private Image bckGround_img;
 private Thread t;
 boolean left;
 boolean right;
 boolean up;
 boolean down;
 int lastpressed;
 int newlastpressed;

 private String drawFps = "0";
    public GameCanvas(int w,int h){
        this.frameW=w;
        this.frameH=h;
        this.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        this.setBounds(0,0,frameW,frameH);
        this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public GameCanvas(int w,int h,Color bck){
        this.frameW=w;
        this.frameH=h;
        this.bckGround=bck;
        this.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        this.setBounds(0,0,frameW,frameH);
        this.setBackground(bckGround);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addNotify(){
        super.addNotify();
        this.createBufferStrategy(2);
        this.buff=this.getBufferStrategy();
        requestFocus();
        startGame();
    }
    public void startGame(){
        if (t==null){
            t=new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
    }
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            long beginTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
//          try {
//              Thread.sleep(25);
//          } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//              e1.printStackTrace();
//          }
            Update();
            Render();
            Draw();
            fps=System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime ;
            long sleepTime=period-fps;
            if (sleepTime == 30) sleepTime = -1;
            fps= ONE_SECOND_MILI / ((period * 2) - sleepTime);
            try{
                if (sleepTime > 0){
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    }
    public void Render(){
        graph = buff.getDrawGraphics();

        if (!HasImgBackground()){
            graph.setColor(bckGround);
            graph.fillRect(0, 0, frameW, frameH);
        }else{
            graph.drawImage(bckGround_img, 0, 0, frameW, frameH,null);
        }
        graph.setColor(new Color(255,255,255));
        graph.drawString("FPS: " + fps , 10, 15);
        Paint(graph);
    }
    private void Draw(){
        if(!buff.contentsLost()){
            buff.show();
            if(graph != null){
                graph.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean HasImgBackground(){
        if (bckGround_img==null){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void setBackgroundImg(Image image){
        this.bckGround_img=image;
    }
    public void deleteBackground(){
        this.bckGround_img=null;
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            left=true;
            if(lastpressed!=4)
                newlastpressed=lastpressed;
            lastpressed=4;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            up=true;
            if(lastpressed!=1)
                newlastpressed=lastpressed;
            lastpressed=1;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            right=true;
            if(lastpressed!=2)
                newlastpressed=lastpressed;
            lastpressed=2;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            down=true;
            if(lastpressed!=3)
                newlastpressed=lastpressed;
            lastpressed=3;
        }

    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            left=false;
            if(up||right||down)
                if(newlastpressed!=0)
                lastpressed=newlastpressed;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            up=false;
            if(left||right||down)
                if(newlastpressed!=0)
                lastpressed=newlastpressed;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            right=false;
            if(up||left||down)
                if(newlastpressed!=0)
                lastpressed=newlastpressed;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            down=false;
            if(up||right||left)
                if(newlastpressed!=0)
                lastpressed=newlastpressed;
        }

    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
    abstract void Update();
    abstract void Paint(Graphics g);
}
```

main.java

```
package Game;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Mainth extends GameCanvas{

    private long timeDown = 0;
//  private StopWatch t = new StopWatch();
    static Collision coll=new Collision();
    Character character=new Character();
    static Image wallImage=ImageLoader.getImg().getImage("data/images/objects/brick_wall.png");
    static Image bushImage=ImageLoader.getImg().getImage("data/images/objects/hedge_ver.png");
    static ArrayList<Image> wallArray=new ArrayList<Image>();
    static ArrayList<Image> wall2Array=new ArrayList<Image>();
    static Sprite wallSprite;
    static Sprite wall2Sprite;
    static IndexCounter devIndex;
    static Dude dev;
    static Wall wall;
    static Wall bush;
    static Wall wall2;
    /**not used*/
    int x=0,y=0;
    static ArrayList objects=new ArrayList<Entity>();
    static ArrayList chars=new ArrayList<Dude>();
    static ArrayList projectiles=new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Mainth Canvas=new Mainth(1500,1000);
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(Canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(750, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Mainth.chars.add(dev);
        Mainth.objects.add(wall);
        Mainth.objects.add(bush);
        Mainth.objects.add(wall2);
    }
    public Mainth(int w,int h){
        super(w,h);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        CharacterCreation();
    }
    public void CharacterCreation(){
        wallArray.add(wallImage);
        wall2Array.add(bushImage);
        wallSprite=new Sprite(wallArray,1);
        wall2Sprite=new Sprite(wall2Array,1);
        dev=new Dude(character.LinkStandingDown,character.LinkStandingDown.getID(),100,300);
        devIndex=new IndexCounter(character.LinkWalkingDownArray.size(),3);
        wall=new Wall(wallSprite,1,100,50){};
        bush=new Wall(wall2Sprite,1,185,55){};
        wall2=new Wall(wallSprite,1,100,225){};
        bush.setHardness(1);
    }
    Movement movem=new Movement();
    void Update() {
        movem.movement(dev, character, left, right, up, down, lastpressed, devIndex);
        dev.move();
        coll.objectCollision(chars,objects);
        devIndex.Counter();
    }
    void Paint(Graphics g) {
        bush.Draw(g,0);
        wall.Draw(g,0);
        wall2.Draw(g,0);
        dev.Draw(g,devIndex.getIndex());
        Graphics2D g2d= (Graphics2D) g;
    }
    public void animation(){
        String[] animationSprites=dev.getImgs("walk_down");
        int aniTime=0;
        aniTime++;
    }
    public ArrayList<Entity> exportObjects(){
        return objects;
    }
    public ArrayList<Dude> getMainChar(){
        return chars;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"..i would like help as soon as possable .. any advice is welcome."* 1) Start you projects sooner. (And don't tell us your time-schedule) 2) Add the homework tag to homework questions. 3) Use an upper case letter for the first letter in every sentence, as well as the word I. 4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

What exactly isn't working in the game?

Basic side scrolling logic consists of moving the background, the characters, and the obstacles a certain increment as movement keys are held down. If the screen is "moving right," we are actually moving all of these elements to the left. If the screen is "moving left," then we are doing the opposite. Also, if an entity is moving and has a certain target point, make sure and update the coordinates of this point as you scroll, or the entity will keep moving until it reaches its original on-screen destination. You should also implement code that stops the screen from scrolling too far (thus losing the game).

There are many ways to use side-scrolling, such as scrolling when a character moves a certain distance from the center of the screen, or having controls that move the screen independently from a character (such as in an rts when one scrolls around the map). An easier way might be to always have the player be in the center of the screen, and just have the background and other entities scroll back and forth around him.

Comment: nothing is broken i just cant figure out side scrolling because i just started programming 1 and half months ago i just want to make a scrolling system so i can have a nice RPG to show at my presentation at my school

heres my source code from eclipse http://www.mediafire.com/?fi1f9lv6qc2t5d7

Answer (score 1):

You need to coordinate systems:

- world coordinates - are always constant
- (local) frame coordinate - where objects should be shown in your window now

every object has only world coordinates. And you have a window in this big world. This window has its coordinates in world coordinates. To scroll the view in your window you just need to change it's world coordinates.

Of course you need a code, that renders all objects in you window for any correct position of your movable window. It can be like:

```
void renderFrame(Rectangle frame) {
    for(GameObject go : gameObjects) {
        if(frame.contains(go.getGlobalCoordinates())) {
            Rectangle windowCoordinates = new Rectangle();
            windowCoordinates.x = go.getGlobalCoordinates().x - frame.x;
            windowCoordinates.x = go.getGlobalCoordinates().y - frame.y;
            windowCoordinates.x = go.getGlobalCoordinates().width - frame.width;
            windowCoordinates.x = go.getGlobalCoordinates().height - frame.height;

            go.paint(g2, windowCoordinates);
        }
    }
}
```